# design for a database interfacing API for inserting and deleting Domain objects

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, single-responsibility-principle, object-oriented-analysis

I'm trying to create a good OOP design especially conforming to SRP for interfacing with a database to insert and delete `Customer`s. My focus is on design rather than getting bogged down by details of SQL and JDBC or datasources. So I've left simple implementations using printlines. But I'm wondering if this is how springs jdbctemplate is designed..

This effort came about while I was learning about the SRP OOP design principle. A poorly designed `Customer` class violated SRP since it contained database insert/delete responsibility. I pulled out code from `Customer` class and put it into a class that inherits from an `RdbmsManager` base class who's responsibility is to establish connections and interact with the database.   I'm not sure about weather this is a good design, and I'm also not sure if some database API object similar to `jdbcTemplate` or something needs to be provided to child classes to interact with the database.

**`Customer` class**

```
public class Customer {

    private int id;
    private String fullName;
    private boolean active;

    public Customer(int id, String name, boolean active){
        this.id = id;
        this.fullName = name;
        this.active = active;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", active=" + active
                + "]";
    }   
}
```

The parent database access class:

```
public class RdbmsManager{

    public RdbmsManager(){
           connectToDatabase();
    }

    private void connectToDatabase(){
           // read from properties files to get DB URL, PORT number etc.
           // Create Datasource object and establish connection to database
           System.out.println("Established Database Connection...");
    }

   // Below method returns the database object children can use to issue commands
    protected DatabaseAPI getDatabaseObject(){
        DatabaseAPI databaseObject = new DatabaseAPI ();
           return databaseObject;
    }

}
```

CustomerDataManager child class:

```
public class CustomerDataManager extends RdbmsManager{

    public CustomerDataManager() {
        super(); // call to super will establish database connection from parent class
    }

    public void saveCustomerToDatabase(Customer Customer) {
        getDatabaseAPI().insert(Customer);
    }

    public void deleteCustomerFromDatabase(Customer Customer) {
        getDatabaseAPI().delete(Customer);
    }
}
```

Simple implementation for the database interaction object to focus on design:

```
public class DatabaseAPI{

    protected void insert(Object object){
           System.out.println("inserted the into the database: "+ object.toString());
    }

    protected void delete(Object object){
           System.out.println("Deleted object from database" + object.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: why was this question requested for close??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're pretty close to what is one of the standard designs to working with databases.
The main difference is in the name of the classes (e.g.  DAO instead of Manager), and that you are extending the DB connection pool manager in order to create the DAOs.

**Let me elaborate a little bit:**

1. The database should be separated by abstraction from your application. In order to achieve this, you usually create what's known as a `data abstraction layer` on top of the database. This is a little bit similar to your `RdbmsManager` class, and its point is to abstract away the actual DB used. In order to achieve this, you normally have a database access interface of some kind which will be implemented by some class controlling all connections to the DB (try to avoid names containing 'Manager' since it doesn't really help clarify what those classes do). If later on you decide to change the DB you're using, all you need to do is create a new implementation to the interface that supports the new DB, and you're pretty much done !
2. Access to the actual data in the database should also be abstracted by another layer, usually called `data access layer`. This layer contains interfaces that encapsulate all access to specific type of data (per table usually), and enable `CRUD` operations to be performed on them. Those interfaces are generally named `SomethingDAO` where 'Something' stands for the type of object being accessed (the 'DAO' part stands for: 'Data Access Object'). Again, the implementations of those interfaces should be DB specific and be changed when you replace the DB you use with another.
3. The data should be transferred to the client code (usually the business/application layer) using some other method, usually `DTO`s (stands for 'Data Transfer Object'). These are (again) interfaces which expose some functionality required from the objects being represented in the DB, which should be implemented by DB specific (or generic, it depends) classes.

This is the theory in short. There are many data sources online (not to mention books) that will allow you to read much more about it.

On a different note, this is just one way to implement DB connectivity. There are numerous others, since there are a lot of design patterns that refer to enterprise applications in general, and to inter-tier communications in particular. Let me refer you to what I consider the best source for those design patterns: [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008OHVDFM)

**Edit 1:**
Here's a really simplistic code example (untested of course - treat as pseudo code):

```
public interface Customer { ... }

public interface CustomerDTO implements Iterable<Customer> { ... }

public class CustomerDTOSQLImpl {
    public CustomerDTOSQLImpl(ResultSet resultSet) { ... }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Customer> iterator() { ... }

    ...
}

public interface CustomerDAO {
    public CustomerDTO findById(int id);

    ...
}


public class CustomerDAOSQLImpl {
    @Inject
    private Connection connection;

    @Override
    public CustomerDTO findById(int id) {
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE ID = ?");
        statement.setInt(1, id);
        return new CustomerDTOSQLImpl(statement.executeQuery());
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Basically what i want is to make sure that CustomerDataManager or CustomerDAO as your suggestion, does not have to change when the database changes. Would this design achieve that level of abstraction?

Comment: Well, the 'CustomerDAO' will not change, but you'll have to add a new 'CustomerDAOImpl' class per supported DB type. I don't think there's any way to create a single generic implementation.

Comment: Hmm, if you can please elaborate on the dao and dao impl. Could u show a code sample for this?

Comment: Should I really be extending from the manager? I'm thinking maybe I should make the DatabaseManger a singleton that provides the one and only instance of the Connection object.. In terms of design what would you say is better?

Comment: That's exactly right. The DB manager should be a singleton, and provide the DB connection to the DAOs (preferably via injection).